# After renaming a file the Ubuntu 14.04 program "Files" sorts alphanumerically and displays location of new/corrected file name. Can that be disabled?

Tags: sort

I looked in Ubuntu 14.04 and I could not find a option to disable a awkward feature that made extra work for me.

After renaming a file then the program "Files, version 3.10.1" reorganizes alphanumerically and then automatically moves the prompt/cursor/highlighting to the new file name at the new alphanumerical location. It's much easier and practical if the working cursor remains in the same area where the file was found that needed name changes or needed name spelling corrections. Windows 7 does what I ask about and it's a huge improvement over that auto sort *and then go to the new file location*. A example to consider is a file is in the "A" area and then you rename it to a "Z" and you are then taken to the "Z" stuff and need to scroll hundreds of lines back to the "A" section. It's annoying.

Thanks for reading and taking the time.

Comment: Can you please clarify the title?

Comment: Title fixed and cleaned up. Done. Thanks for the heads up. I agree that it was a awkward read.